# Maximise subset selection under constraints

Tags: algorithm, subset

I am working on a scheduling problem for a team of volunteers. I have boiled my problem down to the following algorithmic problem:

I have a matrix with ~60 rows representing volunteers and ~14 columns representing days. Each entry is an integer in the range 0 to 3 inclusive representing how free the volunteer is on that day. I want to choose exactly 4 entries from each column (4 volunteers a day) such that (in order of importance)

1. A 0-entry is never chosen.
2. The workload is as spread out as possible (first give everyone one shift, then start giving out second shifts, etc. We can expect that most volunteers will only have one shift per 2-week period, and some may even have none.)
3. The sum over selected entries is maximised (volunteers get days that they prefer).

I want to output a decision matrix that has a 1 whenever a volunteer is chosen for a day, and 0 otherwise. I believe this is an instance of the nurse-rostering problem, so I'm not expecting a fast solution, but I just want to make a brute force algorithm that will work in a reasonable time for my ~60 person team. I'm just really not sure how to start tackling this problem. Is it suited for backtracking, or is there some way to calculate the best placement of each volunteer based on the distribution of his/her day-scores?

Comment: What is the question here? As you already decided on doing it brute-force, why not present your progress there? What's the problem? What's brute-force for you? From a formal perspective, those constraints are conflicting (e.g. 2 vs. 3) and therefore the task is (currently) not well-defined.

Comment: I guess I should clarify that 3 is less important than 2. Volunteers are asked to rate how much they want to work on a given day so we should choose 3-entries over 2-entries over 1-entries.

Comment: I recommend a linear-programming / integer-programming approach which imho will be hard to beat even with more advanced backtracking-backed custom-algorithms. But you should not expect someone to write the model down for you, as the decisions to make are very very dependent on the exact problem and the descriptions is still ambiguous (even after the edits; people often underestimate the problems behind multi-objective optimization).

Comment: @sascha Thanks for your suggestion. I have resolved to rewrite my program in Python and use an integer programming solver. I will update the post if I find a solution.

Comment: Maybe it can be turned into a flow network problem?